# Best approach to enforce loading of scripts

Tags: development, 2013

I've built a responsive SharePoint layout and although this is working in my main page, I'd now like to enforce this across the farm.

I can see a few ways to do this (feature, edit masterpage) but I'm wondering what would be the best way to ensure that the following lines are always executed when each page is loaded, and early into the loading process:

```
<script src="http://sharepoint/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://sharepoint/scripts/tiles.js"></script>
<script src="http://sharepoint/scripts/SharepointMenu.js"></script>
<script src="http://sharepoint/scripts/growHeader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sharepoint/scripts/tiles.css" />
```

Comment: That would be an AdditionalPageHead delegate control printing out these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Script manager.Here is the link in how to implement it:
http://labs.steveottenad.com/adding-javascript-to-sharepoint-2010-master-page/